# How to show custom module direct in catalog tpl file in oc2

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

I have read all the related questions in SO and Opencart Forum but couldn't find solution.

So I have copy featured module and edited some of code, not too much and Now i want to show this new module direct in front on only success page. So i have put this code in ***catalog/controller/checkout/success.php***

```
$data['successpage'] = $this->load->controller('module/successpage');
```

and in ***catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/success.tpl

```
<?php echo $successpage; ?>
```

Now i getting

> error Undefined index: limit in controller\module\successpage.php on line 20

*** I think its b'coz some variables values need to send in module controller file**

And i have try all the answer for this but can't get solution.

Thanks If you know and help me to sort out.

Comment: Show the code of `controller\module\successpage.php`.

Comment: same as featured module only controller and tpl call line change in file

Comment: can you show your code ?

Comment: hello, you can check code here http://pastebin.com/jJVjZ4md

Comment: As i understand, You want to use featured module on success page. Correct ?

Comment: `Unkonwn index limit`, this is due to setting in admin for this custom module. ie. `successpage`

Comment: then how i fixed it..some idea..

Comment: You want to use featured module on order success page. Correct ?

Answer (score 1):

You might get an error as there is not any settings (data) is passed in index method of your class `ControllerModuleSuccesspage`. You are directly calling `$data['successpage'] = $this->load->controller('module/successpage');`

Try to display your `successpage` module by setting from admin side. (From layout). If you want to call it directly then first check for condition `if ($setting['any index']) { ..... } else {... }`.

If you want to pass any parameter without setting up from admin side than do this.

```
$parameters = array(
 'name' => 'Your module name',
 'product' => array(43,40,42,30), // product id
 'limit' => 4,
 'width' => 200 ,
 'height' => 200,
 'status' => 1
);

$data['successpage'] = $this->load->controller('module/successpage',$parameters);
```

You will get all details of `$parameters` in `index` method of your `successpage` controller file.
That's it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this url " [yourhost]/index.php?route=module/successpage" to see if this module is working perfectly. There is no error in loading this module to parent controller. I think issue is present in this module itself. Maybe some value dependency.

Comment: thanks for answer, yes, error show after running url which also show in featured module, bestseller module and in all..even you can also check  [yourhost]/index.php?route=module/featured